# Apache POI Excel Macro performance

Tags: java, excel, vba, apache-poi

I have an excel macro with multiple sheets. On one of the sheets there are several inputs that are required for a very complex formula that uses multiple sheets with some lookup tables. I will have to use that formula to compute fast some value for thousands of users concurrently (in a java server app)

Now, I know the proper way to do it would be to translate the formula into code and use that but I was wondering if there is any way I could use Apache POI for that. Something like:

1. Load the xlsm file into memory
2. Modify the input parameters of the macro
3. Read the output value

Any idea on how to do this in a scalable manner?